# It is necessary to fill in the file from the keyboard with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

The desired file is accessed, but the file is not even opened and therefore nothing can be written into it.
I want it to open a file to which the path is specified when I click the button, and I can enter text directly into the file. I don't want the text box option, because I plan to work with a lot of text.
There are no errors. I just can't even open the file. My program ends with code 1. That's why I don't understand how to solve the problem.

```py
from tkinter import *
window=Tk()
window.title("Simple archiver")
window.geometry('500x500')
window.resizable(False,False)

from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

def openfile():
    tf = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="PATH.txt",
        filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
    )
    tf = open(tf,"w")
    tf.write(input())
    tf.close()

button = ttk.Button(window, text="Open", command=openfile)
button.place(y=200,x=150)
```

Comment: What exactly happens, what should happen? If there are error messages, show them as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: If you want to *save* something to file (since you use "w" mode in `.open()`), use `asksaveasfilename()` instead of `askopenfilename()`.  `initialdir` option expects a path, not filename. Also avoid using `input()` (console input) in a GUI application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *"I don't want the text box option, because I plan to work with a lot of text."* - Using a text box is a better option to input text in a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but its not readily apparent.

If you add a text prompt to the `input()` statement you'll see that it wants input from the console.

You could instead havw input from a Text or Entry widget. See example below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
window.title("Simple archiver")
window.geometry('500x200')
window.resizable(False,False)

def openfile():
    tf = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="PATH.txt",
        filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),) 
    )
    tf = open(tf,"w")
    tf.write(textarea.get('1.0', 'end')) # Getting text from Text widget
    tf.close()

textarea = Text(window, width=50, height=5)
textarea.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

button = ttk.Button(window, text="Open", command=openfile)
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```